# Can I create JSON to Java POJO at runtime?

Tags: java, json, rest, jsp-tags

I have a requirement where I am getting the JSON response from REST API.

I can create a POJO and convert the JSON to JAVA but this particulat POJO is of no use for me in future or in other functionality.

Hence I was thinking to convert the JSON to Java dynamically using any API and render the objects in the JSP.

Can you tell me is this a good practise and how can I do that?

Expected JSON Response:

```
{
"_id": "",
"title": "",
"contact": "",
"country": "",
"children": [
   {
     "title": "",
      "contact": "",
      "country": "",
      "children": [
          {
            "title": "",
            "contact": "",
            "country": "",
            "children": []
           }
          ]
        }
      ]
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good practice since doing the conversion to an actual Java POJO you are verifying the JSON is correct in some way according to what you expect to receive, not a real verification but better than nothing.

In any case, if you don't want to have an actual Java POJO you can use a Map<String,Object> to store the data and render it in the jsp, you can use Jackson library to accomplish that conversion.

Regards.

UPDATE FOR QUESTION:

It looks quite simple with that schema, you can use the same class as parent and children, something like this:

```
public class YourPojo implements Serializable {
    private String _id; // not good practice start by underscore
    private String title;
    private String contact;
    private String country;
    private List<YourPojo> children;

    // constructors, getters, setters...
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, if genreating POJO is a good practice then I will go for it.
I have provided the JSON output I will be getting, and the children level can go down upto maximum 8 levels or less.
Can you tell me my how my POJO should look like as I tried online tool and it gave me 1 Category class and 2 Child subclasses but as I mentioned earlier it is not fixed how many level of Childern I may get, so I really want to have it generic.

Comment: I added the example to me reply.

Comment: No, this POJO won't fit in my case as the Child schema doesn't have Id

So I am planning to have 1 paresnt class with all the fields you have defined along with private List<Children> children;

And Children class will have same fields except the id.

Comment: That is right, you can have two classes for that, other option would be to use the same but having the _id property as null for children.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an approach similar to what you have in XML: parse the JSON into a generic structure (DOM for XML) and then use configurable means to extract the data you are interested in e.g. XPath for XML or JSONPath for JSON.

This means you end up with code that can handle any well-formed JSON and that can be used to extract any part of the message through configuration.